# Get LoginUserId in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have used this method

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
     var currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

But I am getting `Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

And I am also not able to get Web-security and the Login user id as in mvc4

Comment: Is `.GetUserId()` a custom method? I don't have it available, so the error should be located there

Comment: @Serv using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use code like below it may help you

```
public ImportFormFromExcelController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }

    public ImportFormFromExcelController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    public Guid getLoginUserInfoId()
    {
        Guid loginUserInfoId = new Guid();
        string loginUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var searchLoginUserInfoId = from m in db.UserInfos
                                    where
                                        m.UserID == loginUserId
                                    select m;
        foreach (var c in searchLoginUserInfoId)
        {
            loginUserInfoId = c.UserInfoID;
        }
        return loginUserInfoId;
    }
```

and recieve your login id like

```
Guid loginUserInfoId = getLoginUserInfoId();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from one of my code snippets, where I use 1 DbContext to manage both, Identity and Model-first classes.

Asuming you have not extended your `IdentityUser` model, you can use this method to retrieve the userId:

```
//Id in Identity is Guid; returning as string for simplicity
public string GetUserId(string username)
{
    var um = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(
                 new UserStore<IdentityUser>(
                     new IdentityDbContext()));
    return um.FindByName(username).Id;
}
```

If you have extended your Identity Model with custom properties and therefore created your own model

```
public class CustomUserModel : IdentityUser
{
}
```

... you need to change the above code accordingly

```
var um = new UserManager<CustomUserModel>(
             new UserStore<CustomUserModel>(
                 new IdentityDbContext()));
```

The same goes for `IdentityDbContext`, which is your DbContext-class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When i retruning the userid in other method as  string um = GetUserId;
i am getting error Cannot convert method group'getuserid' to non-delegate type string

Comment: I did not understand that.

Comment: i want the login userid to be  called in other method of a controller where it get the login user id and send its value to other table

Comment: This is another question altogether and is not part of the problem you described above.

Comment: That is the only reason why i need login user id

Answer (score 0):

This Solve My Problem

```
var LoginuserId=User.Identity.GetUserId();
```